# Query a MySQL Database and Group By Date Range to Create a Chart

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to create the following chart from a MySQL database. I know how to actually create the chart (using excel or similar program), my problem is how to get the data needed to create the chart. In this example, I can see that on January 1, 60 tickets were in the state illustrated by the green line.

[image]

I need to track the historical state of tickets of a project through a date range. The date range is determined by a project manager (in this case it's January 1st through January 9th).

For each ticket, I have the following set of historical data. Each time something changes in the ticket (state, description, assignee, customer update, and other attributes not shown in this problem), a "timestamp" entry is made in the database.

```
ticket_num      status_changed_date     from_state  to_state
123456          2011-01-01 18:03:44     --          1
123456          2011-01-01 18:10:26     1           2
123456          2011-01-01 14:37:10     2           2
123456          2011-01-02 07:55:44     2           3
123456          2011-01-03 06:12:18     3           2
123456          2011-01-04 19:03:43     3           3
123456          2011-01-05 02:05:24     3           4
123456          2011-01-06 18:13:28     4           4
123456          2011-01-07 13:14:48     4           5
123456          2011-01-09 01:35:39     5           5
```

How can I query the database for a given time (determined by my script) and find out what state each of the tickets are in?

For example: To produce the chart shown above, given the date 2011-01-02 12:00:00, how many tickets were in the state "2"?

I've tried querying the database with specific dates and ranges, but can't figure out the proper way to get the data to create the chart.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is a ticket's "from_state" always match the most recent "to_state"?  That was my initial interpretation, but your sample entry at 2011-01-04 19:03:43 appears to violate this condition.

Comment: Are you trying to see what the final state was at the end of the day, or the start of the day?  So if we say the state of 123456 on 1/1/11, it's state was "2" because it ended the day at 2 or "null" because it started the day as "null"?

Comment: @Pursuit The ticket's "from_state" will not always make the "to_state". An example of this is if a ticket is set to "solved" when in fact it wasn't solved, so the state moved back to "open".

Comment: @Will I'm trying to find out the state at a very specific point in time. The example in the problem (2011-01-01 12:00:00) needs to be edited to show a point in time after the beginning time for this specific ticket example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so if you are trying to get a count of records in a certain state at a certain time, I think a stored proc might be necessary.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spStatesAtDate
    @Date datetime,
    @StateId int
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   SELECT COUNT(*) as Count
   FROM ticket_table t1
   WHERE to_state = @StateId AND status_changed_date < @Date
        AND status_changed_date = (SELECT MAX(status_changed_date) FROM ticket_table t2 where t2.ticket_num=t1.ticket_num AND status_changed_date < @Date)
END
```

then to call this for the above example, you're query would look like

```
EXEC spStatesAtDate @Date='2011-01-02 12:00:00', @StateId=2
```

Comment: I didn't think of introducing a stored procedure for this problem, good advice. I appreciate the tip.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I feel that this answer is the best choice because it accounts for all records historically.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure I know what you want.  But . . .

Assuming a table definition like:

```
create table ticket_data (ticket_num int,
                          status_changed_date datetime,
                          from_state int,
                          to_state int);
```

The following, for example would give you the number of values per day:

```
select date(status_changed_date) as status_date, count(*)
from ticket_data
group by status_date;
```

Now, if you want just `from_state = 2`, just add a where clause in to that effect.  If you want just the ones on Jan 2, then add in `where date(status_changed_date) = '2011-01-02'`

Or, if you you're looking for the distinct number of tickets per day then, change `count(*)` to `count(distinct ticket_num)`

Is this what you're asking?   SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b707/7)

Comment: Works great thanks! I changed the group by variable so it would work to those people with the same issue.  I'll programmatically insert the date and status to get each count which will then allow me to create the chart.

Comment: YW. One additional thing -- if you're going to be querying for each status/date, it might be better to use GROUP BY and HAVING clauses.  GROUP BY both date and status, and then putting your date range into the HAVING.

Comment: Initially I thought this answer was the best choice, but it doesn't quite account for historical data (if a ticket changed status on a date prior to the date in the query). I appreciate the SQL Fiddle since I didn't know that existed before this question.

Comment: Your call.  But you don't need a stored proc to make these kind of requests, nor do you need to do multiple queries.  My initial answer was intended to be partially a leading question since I still don't see exactly what the y-axis really is in your sample graph.

Comment: True, I didn't end up using a stored procedure, but I didn't see a way around not needing a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to select the last modification date before a given point grouped by ticket_num and then select the states at this time.

```
SELECT 
  ticket_num,
  to_state,
  status_changed_date
FROM
  tickets
WHERE 
status_changed_date IN (
  SELECT MAX(status_changed_date)
  FROM tickets
  WHERE status_changed_date < '2012-02-01 01:00:00'
  GROUP BY ticket_num
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to common question: how to get list of items and their most recent statuses.  So. Given one issue, we can get its most recent status with query:

```
select to_state 
from ticket_states 
where ticket_num = t.ticket_num 
order by status_changed_date desc 
limit 1
```

Next, we need to get all applicable distinct issue ids, which is a simple distinct select:

```
select distinct ticket_num from ticket_states
```

With these two subqueries we can already start building. For example, current list of issues and their latest statuses before specified date would be:

```
select t.ticket_num
     , (select to_state 
        from ticket_states 
        where ticket_num = t.ticket_num
        and status_changed_date <= '2012-01-01'
        order by status_changed_date desc 
        limit 1) as last_state
from (select distinct ticket_num 
        from ticket_states) t;
```

All issues, which were non-existant at at the specified time will have `last_state` set to null.

This probably isn't the best way of doing this, but it is first which came to mind. I'll leave other stuff to you. Also I should mention that this is not a very efficient solution also.

Comment: This would work, but as you mentioned it isn't quite as efficient. I appreciate the help though.