# Group data on weekly (Sunday - Saturday) basis

Tags: sql, mssql-jdbc

I am stuck with following problem. How can I group following data in the way that it will sum up count on weekly basis.

```
    +---------------------+-----+
    |          data       |count| 
    +---------------------+-----+
    | 2012-08-01 00:00:00 |  4  | 
    | 2012-08-02 00:00:00 |  5  | 
    | 2012-08-03 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-04 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-05 00:00:00 |  8  | 
    | 2012-08-06 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-07 00:00:00 |  8  | 
    | 2012-08-08 00:00:00 |  6  | 
    | 2012-08-09 00:00:00 |  2  | 
    | 2012-08-10 00:00:00 |  0  | 
    | 2012-08-11 00:00:00 |  5  | 
    | 2012-08-12 00:00:00 |  4  | 
    | 2012-08-13 00:00:00 |  4  | 
    | 2012-08-14 00:00:00 |  0  |        
    +---------------------+-----+
```

The week should be calculated in the Sunday - Saturday format.....

Comment: Check related questions first. I.e. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182644/query-a-mysql-database-and-group-by-date-range-to-create-a-chart?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597101/weekly-total-sums?rq=1)

Comment: What database are you using?  I am guessing SQL Server from the "mssql-jdbc", but you should explicitly tag the question.

Comment: I tried following query...but not getting the result in Sunday - Saturday format                                                                                                select DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,data), 0) as Monday, sum(count)
                    from table
                    where data>getdate()-30 
                    group by DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week,0,data), 0);

Answer (score 3):

Subtract the day of week from the date (assuming there's no time part) and then group by it:

```
select 
   dateadd(day, -(DATEPART(weekday, data) + @@DATEFIRST + 4) % 7, data)
  ,sum([count])
from tab
group by 
   dateadd(day, -(DATEPART(weekday, data) + @@DATEFIRST + 4) % 7, data)
```

`(DATEPART(weekday, data) + @@DATEFIRST + 4) % 7` returns a number between 0 (=sunday) and 6 (saturday) independent of the `@@DATEFIRST` setting.

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a23a/2)